# Which remote control software has a multi-desktop feature (I am not sure whether it is the correct name)?

Tags: remote-access, remote-desktop, virtual-desktop

Which remote control software has a multi-desktop feature (I am not sure whether it is the correct name)? When I remote control my office PC from my home PC, no other person can work in my office PC while I am doing some other work remotely. Since both PCs are showing the same screen/desktop. I have tried AnyDesk and Teamviewer. But could not find such a feature. Could anyone suggest a software that has this feature?

Comment: This is a Windows Server feature, not available in other versions of Windows.

Comment: @Tetsujin what feature is that? Any link?

Comment: Multiple simultaneous users/remote connections. You can't do it in any other Windows version except Windows Server. Additionally, you will need to purchase an RDS CAL license, per device or per user. https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/remote/remote-desktop-services/rds-client-access-license